# $G$ has square-free order and a unique subgroup for each prime factor. Prove that $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Consider a finite group $G$ of square-free order, meaning $|G|=p_1p_2\dots p_k$ and no prime $p_i$ is repeated. Suppose that $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $p_i$ for each $i\in\{1,2,\dots,k\}$. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

**My attempt:**

Let $H_i$ denote the unique subgroup of $G$ of order $p_i$. The uniqueness of $H_i$ implies that $H_i \operatorname{char} G$ and thus $H_i \trianglelefteq G,\,\forall i\in\{1,2,\dots,k\}$. Moreover, each $H_i$ is cyclic (prime order).

Since all of the orders of all $H_i$'s are relatively coprime, we can guarantee that $H_i \cap H_{i+1}\cdots H_k=1$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,k-1\}$ (note: this is an intersection of two sets, $H_i$ and a product of the next subsets!).

This means that $H_1\cdots H_k \trianglelefteq G$ and $H_1\cdots H_k \cong H_1 \times \dots \times H_k$. Thus, $|H_1\cdots  H_k|=p_1\cdot \dots \cdot p_k = |G|$, but we know that the product of these $k$ subsets is a subset of $G$. We have now proved $G = H_1\cdots H_k \cong H_1 \times \dots \times H_k$. Since $G$ is isomorphic to a direct product of cyclic groups AND each of the orders are coprime, we can conclude that $G$ is cyclic as well.

I don't know if this is a correct approach/proof, so I'd like to get some feedback from you.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do not see why the product of an element of order $p_2$ and an element of order $p_3$ could not be an element of order $p_1$?

Comment: I'd rather use that $H_i$ acts on $H_j$ by conjugation. If wlog. $p_i>p_j>\phi(p_j)$, the action is necessarily trivial, hence $H_i$ and $H_j$ commute